# Replace ONLY second occurrence in pattern

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string:

```
'hello$ world$ $'
```

How do I remove only the second occurrence of the `$`

Or if I have `str'ing'h`

How do I use `re.sub()` to only remove the second apostrophe?
Without writing a big long function that breaks it into each character finds the index of all the apostrophes etc.

Comment: if you show your attempt then you will get better answers.

Comment: I have tried, what's felt like everything. I spent 1.5 full hours on a test trying to come up with an answer and could not.
Believe me, I know this is not the best formatted question. But can someone please answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'hello$ world$ $'
>>> print ( re.sub(r'^([^$]*\$[^$]*)\$', r'\1:', s) )
hello$ world: $
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[^$]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `$`
  - `\$`: Match a `$`
  - `[^$]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `$`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\$`: Match a `$`

Use this for second problem is replacing second single quote:

```
s = re.sub(r"^([^']*'[^']*)'", r'\1:', s)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, can I ask why is the portion of the pattern outside the capture group the one that gets replaced and not the capture group?...

Comment: Part outside capture group is what you're replacing so that must be outside the capture group.